# Set parameter for number of records to display in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm creating a report where I want to send a parameter for the number of records to display (I do not want to select the number of records in SQL)

I have created a parameter field (?topN) and set the group to use this value which in design mode works well however when I try to set this parameter in vb.net code it does not work. 
The field which also displays the value shows the parameter correctly though. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: when you say it "does not work", what error message (if any) are you getting? Can you give us a code sample?

Comment: +1 for the questions since (at least in Crystal 10) you can't use the RecordNumber function in the regular record filter, you have to put it in the Section Expert code.  So it's a little tricky.

Comment: Sorry - my question was a bit unclear. This is how I set the param: ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("topN", 4). This way the field gets the value but the group does not sort. There's no error message. I'm trying what Mark SQLDev suggested now. Updating later.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the Section Expert, in the Suppress code option:

Recordnumber > ?@topN

Comment: Mark, I think this will work, it's just that I ran into another problem when trying this. The record numbers in my report are not consecutive. Don't know why this could be. I didn't create the original report and as far as I can see Recordnumber is not used elsewhere. Very confusing.

Comment: Then maybe you can just use the Crystal Record Sort to pick the correct top x number of records?

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping, you could use the TOP-N feature of group sorting.